# demo the react native ios app. How to with apple developer account?

Tags: ios, react-native, testing

I have successfully built the react native ios app and tested it with the ios simulator. Can you please suggest to me how do I test and demo a physical ios device? I have got an apple developer account.

Please suggest me steps.

Comment: Check out TestFlight

Comment: sorry I did not understand

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/testflight/

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/190493/testflight-tutorial-ios-beta-testing-2

Answer (score 0):

You can use the test flight app for beta testing for your app. Assuming you have completed all of the apple developer setup, here are some steps you can take to achieve this.

- On XCode, make a build archive by setting the build to a generic iOS device, and go to product => archive

  - Go to window => organizer, and click upload to App store.
  - Go to iTunes connect => my app => and you should see your build in test flight.
  - Download the test flight and connect it with your apple id.
  - Add yourself as a tester, open your test flight app, and you should be able to download the app.

For more details, just view this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3iIr2uN5Yj8&t=721s

Hope this helps!